# How to serialize Color property as ARGB values?

Tags: winforms, serialization, colors, rgb, system.drawing.color

I'm working with Windows Forms designer. It serializes properties of type Color as known name whenever possible. I need it to serialize such properties always as RGB, because I need it later for interop with other system, which can deserialize only from RGB values. 
Is there a way to serialize Color properties always as RGB values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I solved a similar problem.  Hope it helps.

```
  <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore()> _
  Public Property LineColor() As Color
     Get
        Return mLineColor
     End Get
     Set(ByVal value As Color)
        mLineColor = value
     End Set
  End Property

  Public Property LineColorArgbString() As String
     Get
        Return ColorAsString(mLineColor)
     End Get
     Set(ByVal value As String)
        mLineColor = ParseColorArgbString(value)
     End Set
  End Property
```

Comment: I had to use DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute instead of XmlIgnoreAttribute, but your idea did the trick. Thanks Troy